# add js to wordpress with custom attributes

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add the following code to footer of my wordpress website. What would be the best possible way to do it.

```
<script async defer data-pin-hover="true" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto themes, ->Editor find footer.php and paste code snippet..

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp_footer hook to get this script in footer. Place the below code in your themes functions.php file.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_script', 100);
function add_script(){
     echo '<script async defer data-pin-hover="true" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>';
}
```